# Subversion fail on move a file

Tags: svn

I have a subversion repository, and when I move a file, it report the next error:

```
svn mv file1 file2
svn ci -m "Message"

svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (200 OK) in response to COPY request for '/svn/practicas/software/!svn/bc/78/file1'
```

I don't know what is the problem. Can help me anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Does your server has some free disk space where it stores the SVN revisions?

Comment: Yes, there is free space on the server